# Alternating row color using tomahawk dataList

Tags: jsf

I am using MyFaces 1.2 along with Tomahawk for some additional components.  For this particular page, I needed to use a dataList (instead of a dataTable) because I for every item in my collection i need to display multiple rows (so I am unable to use dataTable).

i tried using rowClasses but that doesn't work (i think because i am generating the rows myself).  I also tried binding the rows to a backing bean but that seems to occur only 1x, not for each item.

Any idea how to best implement this using JSF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `<t:dataList>` has no `varStatus` concept similar to `<c:forEach>` and `<ui:repeat>`. You would otherwise be able to do something like this:

```html
<table id="mytable">
    <c:forEach items="#{bean.items}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
        <tr>
            <td class="#{loop.index % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
                <h:outputText value="#{item}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

with

```css
#mytable tr.odd { background-color: #ddd; }
#mytable tr.even { background-color: #eee; }
```

If `<c:forEach>` is not an option for you due to technical limitations as it's a view build time tag, not a render time tag, and you're using Facelets instead of JSP, then you should be able to use `<ui:repeat>` following a similar syntax with the only difference that you need to use `value` attribute instead of `items`.

```html
<table id="mytable">
    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.items}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
        <tr>
            <td class="#{loop.index % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
                <h:outputText value="#{item}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ui:repeat>
</table>
```

But if you aren't using Facelets (even though your previous questions suggests that you're using Facelets), then your best bet is using the CSS3 `nth-child` pseudoselector.

```css
#mytable tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #ddd; }
#mytable tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #eee; }
```

But if the webbrowser used by your target audience doesn't support CSS3 (IE8 and older), then you need to resort to JavaScript/jQuery to add the CSS class during document load.

Comment: this needs to support ie7 as well so can't use css3, jquery should work though.  any reason why i wasn't able to bind each row in the datalist to a backing bean?  or would i need an object for EACH row?

Comment: So, `<c:forEach>` is not an option and you aren't using Facelets? In your previous questions I saw you talking about XHTML files which inherently means that you're using Facelets. Otherwise you could just use `<ui:repeat>` instead.

Comment: no, forEach resulted in errors on the items attribute, couldn't get around it.